# How to give alert using Modal popup extender by clicking delete "image button" on gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

Hi im having a modal popup extender for user confirmation to delete a file in gridview. I have given delete image button on the gridview.on delete image button click in every row of gridview, the control is passed to rowcommand function based on the command name of the image button. Before the control passes to rowcommand, it has to display an alert to delete "Do you want to delete?" if yes it has pass control to delete,if no it should not delete.
Thanks in advance.

this is my gridview_rowcommand function code

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete") {
    try { 
    int selectedrow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());// fetching the row
```

Comment: so what is the problem with the above code? Must you use Modal popup extender?

Comment: can you show your ASPX Code-Behind?

Comment: Are you required to use the AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender?

Comment: Can you show your GridView ASPX code?

Comment: Aspx code
<ItemTemplate><asp:ImageButton ID="delete"  CommandName="GridDelete" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="Delete_Icon.png"/></ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the server side to display the confirmation dialog.  A better approach is to display this before the button posts back.

Here is an example that uses the standard Javascript confirm() dialog.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<Eval("ID")>'  OnClientClick="return confirm('OK to Delete?');" />
```